# Generated web service not receiving parameters

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I've generated my web service from WSDL in Netbeans 7.1. For security concerns, I can't show it, but you can safely assume that it's ok, It's been production tested.

I can call the web-service ok. If I make the function return and then dump it, it even returns the correct values. What is wrong though, it never receives any parameters from the SOAP call. This is the way I invoke it in the `index.jsp`:

```
try {
    Soap.ServiceService service = new Soap.ServiceService();
    javax.xml.namespace.QName portQName = new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://external.example.com/", "ServicePort");
    String req = "<getTimestampCount  xmlns=\"http://external.example.com/\"><msisdn>656</msisdn></getTimestampCount>";
    javax.xml.ws.Dispatch<javax.xml.transform.Source> sourceDispatch = null;
    sourceDispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, javax.xml.transform.Source.class, javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);


        javax.xml.transform.Source result = sourceDispatch.invoke(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(req)));

        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory factory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();  
java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();  
javax.xml.transform.Result stringOut = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer);      
transformer.transform(result, stringOut);  
writer.close();  
out.print(writer.toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

And this is the function that returns the result:

```
public long getTimestampCount(java.lang.String msisdn) throws ParameterException, UnknownException_Exception {
        //TODO implement this method
        System.out.println(msisdn);
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet.");
    }
```

The printing always produces `null`. I can't for the life of me figure out why it's working, finding the right function, but not passing on the values.

---

Also, I've tested it with this code, and the values returned are correct:

```
try {
    Soap.ServiceService service = new Soap.ServiceService();
    Soap.Service port = service.ServicePort();
     // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here

    java.lang.String msisdn = "5";

    // TODO process result here
    long result = port.getTimestampCount(msisdn);
    out.println("Result = "+result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    out.println(ex.getMessage());
    // TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
```

as expected, this returns a value of 5. This would do fine if I wanted to generate the SOAP response by myself, but I would prefer to receive the response, like the first function does - as SOAP.

Anything else I should post to make this easier? If so, say it, and I'll try to provide everything needed.

Comment: I have a few suggestions: (1) try calling your service with soapUI instead (2) are the namespaces correct in your request XML? (3) To make a self contained example that you can post on here, copy the relevant parts of the WSDL to a brand new WSDL and build an example from that. HTH

Comment: @davidfrancis am I right in assuming that the last example is the one I would use in production? Since I've been learning about WebServices, I've foud out that JAX-WS does all the necessary things so that I wouldn't even see SOAP. Does that mean that the returned string was once a SOAP request, the a SOAP response, and I've just gotten back something from JAX-WS, meaning, already parsed version?

Comment: No the example is to post on here so people can help you ! Full example = get help. As for your second question, yes jaxws insulates you from soap mostly, but it helps being able to get the soap XML when you're debugging etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since solved the problem with these webservices, but I still have no Idea what was wrong with this code.

What I ended up doing, was using the standard syntax, like in the last piece of code. That works perfecty.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following namespace to your method. It helped me in fixing the same issue.

```
<tns:getTimestampCount  xmlns:tns=\"http://external.example.com/\"><msisdn>656</msisdn>
</tns:getTimestampCount>";
```